# xcode retain cycle warning only sometimes occurs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

Xcode appears to only sometimes gives the warning "Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle", as shown in the below snippet from my code.

[image]

Is the first block actually safe from a retain cycle, and if so why, or is it unsafe and xcode is incorrectly giving no warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both blocks will lead to a retain cycle. It's just a little harder to detect it for the first one so the compiler doesn't report it.

In your first block, I assume `datePicker` is a property of your object. So your object retains the date picker, which retains the block which retains your object (by capturing self). It's a cycle with 3 objects but a cycle nonetheless.

In your second block this is much more straightforward : your object retains the block and the block retains your object (by capturing self). Its a cycle with only 2 objects easy to identify (hence the warning).

In both cases you should capture self weakly to avoid the retain cycle.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self methodThatRetainsABlock: ^{
    typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf == nil) {
        return;
    }
    // Don't ever use self here, as it will capture it strongly.
    // Use only strongSelf
}];
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. `datePicker` is a property, if it wasn't then would it be safe?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could have View Controller -> Main View -> Date Picker (as a subview) -> Block -> View Controller. Anything can form a loop, you have to really keep your object graph in mind and make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: A view controller retains it's main view through the `view` property. Views retain their subviews.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's scary, not something I consciously consider coming from a java background. Do you know if Swift can have retain cycles issues like this?

Comment: This is one of the hard problems in iOS programming. Swift being reference counted like Objective-C (and not garbage collected like java) the same rules apply and you cloud create reference cycles in the exact same way. The compiler is a little better at detecting them though, but you still have to be very careful.

Answer (score 1):

OnDateChange is sent to a different object, so Xcode doesn't expect there to be any retain cycles (though theoretically it could still happen).

AddOnTap is sent to self, so possibility of it keeping around the block is high. Hence the warning.

Comment: That's just a coincidence of the example I screenshot. I have seen it not give the warning when a self method captures a block which calls self, and visa versa.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the compiler identifies the second block as potentially having a retain cycle is because the compiler only checks retain cycles for functions with names starting with `add` or `set`.

From the [clang documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-421.11.65/src/tools/clang/lib/Sema/SemaChecking.cpp):

1. Checking retain cycles verifies selectors that are "setter like"

```
/// Check a message send to see if it's likely to cause a retain cycle.
void Sema::checkRetainCycles(ObjCMessageExpr *msg) {
  // Only check instance methods whose selector looks like a setter.
  if (!msg->isInstanceMessage() || !isSetterLikeSelector(msg->getSelector()))
    return;

  // Try to find a variable that the receiver is strongly owned by.
  RetainCycleOwner owner;
  if (msg->getReceiverKind() == ObjCMessageExpr::Instance) {
    if (!findRetainCycleOwner(*this, msg->getInstanceReceiver(), owner))
      return;
  } else {
    assert(msg->getReceiverKind() == ObjCMessageExpr::SuperInstance);
    owner.Variable = getCurMethodDecl()->getSelfDecl();
    owner.Loc = msg->getSuperLoc();
    owner.Range = msg->getSuperLoc();
  }

  // Check whether the receiver is captured by any of the arguments.
  for (unsigned i = 0, e = msg->getNumArgs(); i != e; ++i)
    if (Expr *capturer = findCapturingExpr(*this, msg->getArg(i), owner))
      return diagnoseRetainCycle(*this, capturer, owner);
}
```

2. "Setter like" methods start with `add` or `set`

```
/// Check for a keyword selector that starts with the word 'add' or
/// 'set'.
static bool isSetterLikeSelector(Selector sel) {
  if (sel.isUnarySelector()) return false;

  StringRef str = sel.getNameForSlot(0);
  while (!str.empty() && str.front() == '_') str = str.substr(1);
  if (str.startswith("set"))
    str = str.substr(3);
  else if (str.startswith("add")) {
    // Specially whitelist 'addOperationWithBlock:'.
    if (sel.getNumArgs() == 1 && str.startswith("addOperationWithBlock"))
      return false;
    str = str.substr(3);
  }
  else
    return false;

  if (str.empty()) return true;
  return !islower(str.front());
}
```

In your code, if you rename `onDateChangedCallback` to `addDateChangedCallback` or `setDateChangedCallback`, you'll most probably have the same warning.